# First differences vs fixed effects

Tags: fixed-effects-model

I've heard that the results from regressions with first differences and fixed effects yield the same results. If so, why would someone choose one over the other? In fact, I see most people using fixed effects. Is there a reason why?

Comment: First, that is only true for two time periods, and only for the point estimate. The assumptions for obtaining correct statistical inference differ, see e.g. Wooldridge's panel data textbook